# Getting value with jquery

Tags: jquery, twig

I have such script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.price_jq').each(function () {
            var price = $(this);
            alert(price.html());
            var count = price.parent().find('.count_jq');
            alert(count.html());
            sum = (price.html() * count.val());
            $('.cart_total_price').append(sum + "₴");
        });
    });
```

My html

```
<table>
  <td class="cart_price">
     <p class="price_jq">{{ product.price }}</p>
  </td>
     <input size="2" name="count" value="2" class="count_jq" type="text"/>
  <td class="cart_total">
     <p class="cart_total_price"></p>
  </td>
</table>
```

When i alert price i get my value, but when i want get count, i get NaN. What i doing wrong?

Comment: the class is not inside <td>, just place it inside td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code is incorrect, so the input that you are looking for will most likely end up outside the table entirely. It depends on how each browser treats incorrect HTML code.

You need table rows to put the table cells in, and all content in the table has to be inside the table cells. For example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cart_price">
      <p class="price_jq">{{ product.price }}</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input size="2" name="count" value="2" class="count_jq" type="text"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cart_total">
      <p class="cart_total_price"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For the code above you would use `.parent().parent().find('.count_jq')` or `.closest('tr').find('.count_jq')` to find the count element from the price element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.price_jq').each(function () {
        var price = $(this);
        var count = price.closest('tr').find('.count_jq');
        sum = (price.html() * count.val());
        $('.cart_total_price').append(sum + "₴");
    });
});
```

I don't know your requirement, but I think that you might want to add the value to the sum and put it in the element after the loop rather than adding the value for each item in the loop:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.price_jq').each(function () {
        var price = $(this);
        var count = price.closest('tr').find('.count_jq');
        sum += (price.html() * count.val());
    });
    $('.cart_total_price').append(sum + "₴");
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is correct. I put check in 3 minutes